# Vim - Get All Tags Of A Buffer

Tags: vim

I wanna know if anybody is aware about the possibility to get in *Vim* all tags for the current/specific buffer. Should mean ignoring how the tags are generated, don't matter if as a single project file or stored anywhere outside. As long as *Vim* could find tags for that buffer I like to get this whole "snippet" as return. So of cause it's easily possible to search for a tag and get the buffer/file plus position, but how to do this in reverse, having a buffer and getting all related tags?
Of cause I read a lot of documentation and searched a while for it, but it's seems like this direction of working with tags isn't a topic anywhere. Some suggestions by anyone? Thank you!

Comment: 1. This question is too open-ended. 2. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: I want to concatenate tag generation plugin(s) with tag display/outline plugin(s). Second plugins often start to inefficiently generate own their own. I wanna bit unix style here and concatenate two type of applications which are good in one thing. Unfortunately so far they do more than they should, doing it not well and are not rly open to other plugins.

Comment: I would like to have some `getTags(bufid)` function I can use for the display tag plugins, instead of that they calling ctags themself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has the `tagfiles()` and `taglist()` functions. The latter will provide a List of objects that have tag name, filespec, and some attributes. If you pass a regular expression that matches any tag (`.*`), you'll get a (potentially huge) list of all tags.

Tags are not directly scoped to the current buffer. The `'tags'` option provides the sources of tags (which can be queried via the mentioned `tagfiles()`). That option value can be global, or overridden by a particular buffer.

You're right, many tags-related plugins invoke `ctags` et al. directly and parse the output. I guess that's because the `taglist()` function didn't exist in older Vim versions (or it doesn't provide information that the plugin needs).

Comment: Okay. So I can get all tags thats Vim knows an thenI can filter them by their {tagfile} property. Do u think this work?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you could temporarily modify the `'tags'` option to only point to your file, invoke `taglist()`, and then reset the option value. Might be faster if there are many tags files.

Comment: Sry but I don't get what u mean by "your file". Which one do u mean? In fact I simply want to pipe the fitlered output to tagbar, instead of tagbar calling ctags and parse the output of that command call.

Comment: Tagbar only is concerned about the current buffer, right? So "your file" would be `bufname('')`.

Comment: If you want to extend the tagbar plugin itself, I'd recommend to discuss this with the author, and maybe co-develop this.

Comment: Sure, but first I've to provide a solution apprach, haven't I? And at least by this I can open a PR maybe.